# How to decorate Stream instance from a source using IO resources

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

As you know, an Stream generated from a IO resources needs to be closed explictly.

I would like to have a class that decorates a passed Stream, but unfortunately, given filter operations are intermediate, they just create a new instance, so I loose control fo the closing

```
Stream<T> removeNulls(Stream<T> input){
    input.filter(Objects::nonNull) //At this point, the returned pointer is a whole different stream which does not bind closing to the old one
}
```

If only there was a way to bind the close of the filter stream to the original one... Then this would be possible

```
try (Stream<T> myDecoratedStream = MyClass.removeNulls(myRepo.streamAll())){
   myDecoratedStrean....
}
```

Comment: What actual problem do you want to solve? What you have written in your question, is already possible. The stream returned by `filter` may or may not have a different object identity, still, it will perform the same close operation as the original stream instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `onClose` is what you are after, something like:

```
yourStream.filter(....).onClose(SomeRunnable)
```